# What brackets can I use?

Tags: deck

[image]We would like to put in a fence rail across an existing deck with 2x6" deck boards, with a gate.

This is to act as a passageway from the door to the steps to direct dogs out of the house to the yard in order to prevent the dogs from accessing the rest of the deck without permission.

It is about a 10 ft span and is not intended to act as outside railing at all but would like it to appear to be the same as the deck edge railings.

What brackets could be used that would not have attachment flanges outside the perimeter of the posts.

Comment: "*would like it to appear to be the same as the deck edge railings*" We do not know what your railings look like. **More info is needed**.  where are you attaching brackets ? What kind of posts ?

Comment: Maybe cut holes through the deck? And attach on the under side? Sorry I think if it looks like a rail it may need to meet the side force requirements I agree with Alaska man a photo would help.

Comment: I added a picture of the deck

Comment: are you prepared to access the joist below the floor the floor from beneath? (this will involve cuttung up the ceiling of the room below, if the ceiling is finished)